# Fedora live USB with persistent storage

Tags: fedora

I have created a Live USB of Fedora 22 with `rawrite32`. It works fine, but:

1. How can I save permanently my files?
2. If I download a package, let's say `git`, how can I maintain it permanently?
3. How can I change the keyboard (in the live workstation there is no layout option)?
4. Is it possible to remove the "install Fedora" application?
5. It is possible to run Fedora immediately without clicking"try Fedora"?

Answer (score 4):

You can read details on this at the Fedora wiki: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB#Data_persistence

The high points are:

1. Create your live image with `livecd-iso-to-disk --overlay-size-mb`. Our new Fedora Media Creator tool doesn't support this.
2. Because copy-on-write snapshots are used, every write increases space used, *even when deleting things*. This means it's not really suitable for longterm use.

The main use case of the live environment is for trying things out, including making sure your hardware works. It's also useful for troubleshooting or problem solving if your installed system is messed up. It's *not* really meant for long-term use.

Comment: If it is not meant for long-term use, I wonder how to install fedora on usb. Can you help me?

Comment: @Marco You'll need two USB drives — one to boot from, and the other to install to. Just select the second USB as the disk you want to install onto. This will be a little slow, but should work.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the HP firmware of my computer does not allow me to run that device. So I used a virtual machine. Anyhow, thank you!